# Parsing files in java/android

Tags: java

I have a text file that has is set out like the following

```
Title - Welcome to the Dibb
Date - 13/03/11
Information - Hello and welcome to our website.

Title - Welcome to student room
Date - 06/05/11
Information - Hello and welcome to the student room. We are a online forum that allows previous and current students to ask questions.
```

I need to parse this text file and save things like the title line, date line and the rest will be saved as information. I know how to read the file and save the full file as a string but I am stuck on getting the select information.

**CODE**

This is the code I have used to read the text file

```
helloTxt.setText(readTxt());



}

private String readTxt() {

    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pages);

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int i;
    try {
        i = inputStream.read();
        while (i != -1) {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String str = byteArrayOutputStream.toString();

    return str;

}
```

Comment: It seems like you could just split after the first -. Any problems in that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I need the full line so I can't spilt after the -

Comment: "but I need the full line so I can't spilt after the -" how would you extract fields if you need full line?

Answer (score 1):

Read file line by line

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   // process the line.
}
br.close();
```

If you can guarantee that every line has as maximum one `-` then you can use following pattern.

```
String[] tokens = line.split("\s-\s");
```

For this line

> Title - Welcome to the Dibb

It would give you

```
tokens[0] = "Title";
tokens[1] = "Welcome to the Dibb";
```

Comment: Broken and brittle solution. If Title or Date contain `-` then this will break completely.

Comment: @MathiasSchwarz, so far it does not.

Comment: Regarding the line processing: Wouldn't it be better to read until the first '-', split the string and rtrim/ltrim the two parts?

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used this exact code but it was helped a lot and I have now half way done what I needed to :D

Answer (score 0):

I try to write some classes which can help you to approach your issue

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test4 {

    private List<Information> parser(String data) {

        List<Information> informations = new ArrayList<Information>();
        String blocks[] = data.split("\n\r");

        for(String block : blocks) {
            String[] lines = block.split("\n");
            Information information = new Information();
            information.setTitle((lines[0].split("-"))[1].trim());
            information.setDate((lines[1].split("-"))[1].trim());
            information.setInfo((lines[2].split("-"))[1].trim());
            informations.add(information);
        }

        return informations;
    }

    private  void runner() throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("input.txt");
        String input = "";
        int cc;
        while((cc = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            input += (char) cc;
        }

        List<Information> informations = parser(input);
        for(Information information : informations) {
            System.out.println(information);
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Test4 test4 = new Test4();
        test4.runner();
    }

    class Information {

        private String title;

        private String date;

        private String info;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getDate() {
            return date;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        public String getInfo() {
            return info;
        }

        public void setInfo(String info) {
            this.info = info;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Information [" + (title != null ? "title=" + title + ", " : "")
                    + (date != null ? "date=" + date + ", " : "") + (info != null ? "info=" + info : "") + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used this exact code but it was helped a lot and I have now half way done what I needed to :D

Comment: No matter. if your are satisfy just accept the answer and vote up. Thanks. Do still have another problem with your code?